# Vue.js open a link in a new tab with dynamic html

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a application in Vue.js with a bunch of links in a navbar.

Each of the links need to open a new tab with some html that is specific to the link.

How could I implement this in Vue.js? I am thinking theres a way with vue router, but I am building the page dynamically with whatever html I get back from a server, so I'm not seeing how to do it.

Thank you

Comment: Use `target="_blank"` html attribute.

Comment: which element does this attribute work on?

Comment: `router-link` or `a`

Comment: so when i click on my `router-link`, it will then populate some vue component with my html code and then i set it up so if it goes to this router it will load this component, is that gonna work?

Comment: Router link will transfer your `target` attribute to native `a` tag and hence it will open in new tab.

Comment: Here's a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-williamson-l1e8u